# Load asynchronous images in listView only on scroll

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, lazy-loading, lazylist

So I've got this ListView and its adapter. It's using lazy loading of images with a transition effect from previous image to new.

It works great, but I have a problem and it's that my only reason to use a lazy load is to make scroll smooth. If I need to resort the listview I don't want images to lazy load as the transition is completely unnecessary.

I really don't know how to know inside the adapter whether the user is scrolling or the listview has been resorted. Any help is welcome, I found similar questions but none addressed this issue.

Comment: Take a look at [`Picasso`](http://square.github.io/picasso)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The concept of **LazyLoading** is that it loads the images for the first transition only and the images are cached. If the user again scrolls or if the `ListView` restores, it never downloads it again, images are taken from the local cache present on the device.

There are many Libraries that provide this feature :

1. [Lazy List](https://github.com/thest1/LazyList)
2. [Universal Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)
3. [Volley](https://github.com/mcxiaoke/android-volley)
4. [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/)
5. [Tutorial](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2010/07/multithreading-for-performance.html)

Comment: This wasn't exactly what I was looking for because my images are local, but since they need to be recoded they take a bit of time but thanks to these libraries I added a LRUCache and what I do is async + transition if not in cache, otherwise sync. I will take this as correct answer.